# Show only the filled tables' list on a MySQL database schema

Tags: mysql, database

I'm searching a way to show only the filled tables' list on a MySQL database schema, in other words by filtering out all the empty tables.

I know that I can perform something like that for show all the tables within a database schema:

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'myd_db_schema_name'
```

What if I want to add an additional WHERE condition for show only NOT NULL tables's list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this is the solution:

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'my_db_schema_name' AND table_rows >= 1
```

Instead of using `COLUMNS` I used `TABLES`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it helps but you can use two WHERE Clause with AND

And to filter out the empty Tables you can check if the Table has a row like this:

```
WHERE table_rows >= 1
```

So the full Query would be

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'myd_db_schema_name' AND table_rows >= 1
```

I haven't tried it out but hopefully it works.

Comment: It think not. It thrown an error: Code: 1054. Unknown column 'table_rows' in 'where clause' 0.073 sec.